# Calculating the value of pi using a while loop in Python v3

Tags: loops, python

I am new to this platform and not sure how to write it as code. And I’ve tried doing this question different ways but my value of pi is 3.414 so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

[image: image of the formula I am to use]

```
from math import sqrt

root = sqrt(2)
denominator = sqrt(2 + root)
while 2 * (2 / sqrt(2 + denominator) > 1):
    denominator *= denominator
pi = denominator
print("Approximation of pi: %s" % (round(pi, 3)))
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your code, but the while clause immediately strikes me as off.  You seem to multiply `2` with `a > b`.  While that might work as you expect, it seems like you should work on your code making it slightly more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like (looks more clear to me):

```py
from math import sqrt

root = 2*(2/sqrt(2))
denominator = sqrt(2)
pi = root
while 2 / sqrt(2 + denominator) > 1:
    pi = pi * 2 / sqrt(2 + denominator)
    denominator = sqrt(2 + denominator)
print("Approximation of pi: %s" % (round(pi, 3)))
```